# Using the same codebase for many projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a client that I do small projects for from time to time. The requirement for these projects are very close to the same. I have to create some server side API's for games that do things like store user data and some files from time to time.

I build all these using Rails. This time around I am making the project as generic as possible in order to reuse it as much as possible. Up until know I usually just copy and paste code from other projects and reuse that way.

I typically deploy my rails apps to heroku and just name the app according to the project.

My thought is to do the following.

1. for every new project create a git (branch) named after the project
2. after branching make any modifications to the code base that are spesific to the project
3. create a heroku app for the project at hand and add remote info to the same code base

The other option I suppose would be to create a custom rails generator that would set my projects up to be the same by just running a command. This option seems a bit more involved to me. Mainly because I've never created a gem or generator.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: what's the recommended way to use the same rails app over and over on different projects. I guess what I mean is my main app will be a "boilerplate" starting point for all the projects.

Comment: extract your code in gem or engine when it's possible.